# Getting the Document Location from another Window showing another Domain

Tags: javascript, popup, window, cross-domain

I am trying to get window A (on our domain) open window B (another domain, like YouTube) and I want to show the current document location of window B in window A.

As an example, here is some of the code I am using:

```
var popup;
var popupRelay;

function findPopupURL(){
  var loc=popup.document.location.href
  $('#popuploc').html(loc);
}

function clickPopupLink(){
  var windowProperties='height:500,width:1000,location:1,toolbars:0';//etc etc
  popup=window.open('http://www.youtube.com/','popup',windowProperties);
  popupRelay=setInterval(findPopupURL,1000);
}
```

This code generates this error however:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

Unfortunately the work arounds I keep finding requires me to put code on both domains, which is obviously not possible if Im opening somewhere like YouTube.

What I want to know is, is there a way of getting the document location from another window showing another domain? Can it be done at all? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to spy on what people do on other domains. That is exactly why the Same Origin Policy exists.

Comment: OK. Thanks for giving me a definitive answer.